# How to create a content area that overflows a fixed height background image?

Tags: css

This problem has been driving me crazy.

I am trying to create a blog area that overflows a fixed height background image.
[image: wireframe]

I have not even come close to creating this, and would like help on the starting point. Which of the below 2 options can be used to achieve the result I want:

**Option 1:** a DIV that contains 2 DIVs; 1 for the background image, and 1 for the blog area. That way the container DIV can be transparent to show through the page background, e.g.

```
<div>

    <div style="background-image: url('{{.imageUrl}}')>
    </div>

    <div class="blog" style="background-color:blue">
    </div>

</div>
```

**Option 2:** A DIV with a background image that contains the blog area, but the background image is a fixed height, so that if the blog area expands beyond the height of the image, the div below the image is transparent.

```
    <div style="background-image: url('{{.imageUrl}}')>

        <div class="blog" style="background-color:blue">
        </div>

    </div>
```

I appreciate that the CSS I've included above is missing numerous style properties e.g. margins, position, etc, but at this point, I have tried so many combinations and failed that all I am trying to understand is whether I should go with Option #1 or Option #2

Comment: do you want the background-image fit to blog area or half of the height of blog area?

Comment: @לבני מלכה, I’m looking to make the blog area height variable based on its content, while the background image will have a fixed height eg. 500px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `background-image` to `wrap` div and set `margin/padding`

```css
.blog{
 background-color:blue;
 width:400px;
 margin-left: 52px;
 height: 650px;
}
.wrap{
 background-image: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height:500px;
 padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="blog">
  here is my blog 
   </div>
  <div class="other">
  here is other content 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: that's very close to what I was after. Only differences are: (1) the wrap height will be variable based on the blog height; (2) the the wrap background image will stretch to the full width of the screen; and (3) background image will have max height and be pinned to the bottom right hand corner of its max height. I think I can implement these myself, so appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .parent{position: relative;}
    .parent:before {
        background: url(image);
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .blog{
        background-color: blue;
        width: 80%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: auto;
     }
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:blue">
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, @Manish. I didn't pursue this solution because I am not familiar with breaking out CSS styles of a class like "parent" into 2 different style rules. I may try it one day however.